# Flutter - Inkwell's ripple with FlatButton as child doesnt work

Tags: flutter

I have the following code, what i am trying achieve is I want my FlatButton have native ripple effect. By default flutter material does splash effect and it doesnt feel like native. I tried to wrap my FlatButton with inkwell to solve this somehow when i press on the button it ignores my inkwell widget. How may i solve this?

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () => true,
        splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
        child: FlatButton(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
          ),
          child: Text("Im a text"),
          onPressed: () {},
        ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is in the fact that there is a function being passed to the `onPressed` of the `FlatButton`.

You just need to pass `null` to the `FlatButton`'s `onPressed` for the trigger to go to the `InkWell`'s `onTap`.

Try this:

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () => true,
        splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
        child: FlatButton(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
          ),
          child: Text("Im a text"),
          onPressed: null,
        ));
```

Updated:
Add `InkWell` inside a `Material` widget and replace the `FlatButton` with a `Container` widget

```
Material(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
      ),
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () => true,
        splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
          child: Text("Im a text"),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: i tried this but then i lose the color that is with "color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary", the button becomes transperent

Comment: Well, then why do you need the FlatButton inside the InkWell?

Comment: InkWell with splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory parameters adds the native android ripple animation. This is why i need to use inkwell. FlatButton has custom flutter animation

Comment: Try removing the FlatButton an putting the text in a `Container` widget, and wrap the `InkWell` in a `Material` widget. See the update answer.